# Is the empty interface a way to bypass the type system?

Tags: go

I am learning Go (coming from Python) and the enforced typing system is actually helpful. My very limited understanding of `interface{}` led me to the following code where I retrieve JSON data from an API and return a parsed version. The result can be an object or a list of objects.

```
func getJsonFromApi(endpoint string) (reply interface{}, err error) {
    res, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.42/api/" + endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    err = res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &reply)
    return reply, nil
}
```

It works but I feel uncomfortable by subversing the type system. Is this an expected use of `interface{}`?

I will ultimately change the code to always return an array of objects (and grab the first one in my first use case) but I am curious about the general question.

Comment: This is not a subversion, it *can* be a valid use of `interface{}`. What are you going to do with the returned value? I believe the answer depends largely on that.

Comment: @Riwen: I am not sure I understand your question. I will use the content of the object, or of the list of objects in the remaining part of the program.

Comment: I mean, type safety is there to make you help write cleaner code, right? However, if you're using the the result of the function, for example, to log arbitrary data, in a simple program, or something along those lines, it's a completely valid use case. But generally, define your structs.

Comment: I wouldn't say it bypasses the type system (interface{} *is* a perfectly well defined type, after all), but it changes compile time errors to runtime errors. interface{} has no methods, so there's nothing you can do with a value of this type without type assertions or type switches, and neither is checkable by the compiler. But if you have to process inputs of uncertain types there is nothing else you can do.

Comment: The type system in Go is largely about safety. Interface values are still safe, with the added caveat that any incorrect assertions left unchecked will cause a panic (in order to stop the subsequent code from continuing incorrectly. Again, safety).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty interface, `interface{}`, is an *interface* that specifies zero methods. It can hold values of any type (https://tour.golang.org/methods/14), so it is the type you would use to hold something without knowing the actual type.

It is sometimes necessary in examples like yours, but at the cost of strong typing. I don't think you should feel uncomfortable using it in your example, but you should start feeling uncomfortable if it ends up all over the place.

You can allow the caller of your method to pass in an actual type if you use this signature instead:

```golang
func getJsonFromApi(endpoint string, reply interface{}) (err error) {
```

I would say it is a part of the type system, not a way to bypass it.

Comment: Yes, this is the preferred function signature. it's painful for client callers to deal a return type of `interface{}` as it needs to be type checked to convert back to a concert type. Passing in an `interface{}`, the caller can their own  type & not need any conversion later.

Answer (score 5):

If possible, it's better to use a `struct`. You can use a `map`:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://github.com/manifest.json")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   m := make(map[string]interface{})
   json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&m)
   s := m["icons"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["sizes"].(string)
   println(s == "114x114")
}
```

but as you can see, it gets pretty painful when you need to unwrap to get the actual value. `struct` is much better:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://github.com/manifest.json")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   var m struct {
      Icons []struct { Sizes string }
   }
   json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&m)
   s := m.Icons[0].Sizes
   println(s == "114x114")
}
```